# PHP/HTACCESS Creating link without extensions

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to make user-friendly API for my service. I am trying to make it like Discord API - `https://example.com/api/accounts/<account ID>/<stuff>/`, some expected link examples below:

`https://example.com/api/accounts/1234567890/data/`

`https://example.com/api/accounts/1234567890/inventory/`

`https://example.com/api/accounts/1234567890/servers/`

I tried to make some htaccess tricks, but without any result - website got corrupted (just white page without anything) or account ID was considered as folder (HTTP 404, because I don't want those IDs as folders).

Thank you in advance for your response

Edit 1:

File structure can be really any, I just want it working. But most expected by me would be

```
api
- accounts
  - data
  - inventory
  - ...
- server (example)
- game (example)
```

Edit 2:

My API is OOP - so I can call it from any place. I just need to get data and create new object and call some functions. In my bad-looking API, link was like: `https://example.com/api/accounts/data.php?id=123456789` and in that script I call `$stuff = new StuffObj($id, $other, $stuff, $from, $post);` and function like `$stuff->execute();`. But with new API I can just make GET var, like action and in switch choose what object to use.

Comment: What is the filesystem path that actually handles the request? (You've only posted half a question.)

Comment: use a router/front controller pattern and pass everything `RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]`

Comment: When asking for help, it's important that you show us what you've tried and explain a bit more than just "without any result".

Comment: Edited, I hope it will help more

Comment: "File structure can be really any, I just want it working." - ?! By the sounds of it, you don't currently have an API? Before you implement the "pretty looking" URL structure, you need to have a working API with valid end-points (ie. script(s) that actually handle the request... that accept the `<account ID>` and `<stuff>` and do something with it) - this information is still missing from your question. The suggestion above is for `index.php` to handle everything - is that what you want to do?

Comment: @MrWhite I have working API, but It's OOP so input location if flexible.

Comment: If you have a working API then how do you call it? That is what's missing from your question.

Comment: @MrWhite post edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my bad-looking API, link was like: `https://example.com/api/accounts/data.php?id=123456789`

In that case, to implement a "pretty" URL of the form `/api/accounts/<id>/data/`, you would do something like the following using mod_rewrite in your `/api/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^accounts/(\d+)/data/$ accounts/data.php?id=$1 [L]
```

To make this more "generic", to rewrite a URL of the form `/api/accounts/<id>/<action>/` to `/api/accounts/<action>.php?id=<id>`, assuming `<action>` would only consist of lowercase letters then you could change the above `RewriteRule` to read:

```
RewriteRule ^accounts/(\d+)/([a-z]+)/$ accounts/$2.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Although in your file structure you appear to have "subdirectories"(?) of the `/accounts` directory that also match the basename of the `.php` file? If so, this could be problematic, hence why I have disabled MutliViews above.

> But with new API I can just make GET var, like action

Yes, you could - and would perhaps be preferable - everything is managed by a single entry point (eg. `index.php` - but you can call it anything your like) - However, you need to be specific and decide on this before implementing the "pretty URL" - which is really just cosmetic fluff. In fact, if this is just an API, do you need to implement a "pretty URL" at all?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not exactly what I wanted, but this showed me how to expand it for my subdirs.

Comment: You're welcome. "It's not exactly what I wanted" - Well, that's the thing - you didn't actually state what you wanted.